# Convert Spring webclient error response body from string to object

Tags: java, webclient

In this method the msg variable is returning in string format..how can be conversion of it can be taken place into certain java pojo object.
[Method image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZsXS.jpg)

In place of Mono I tried Mono but it didnt worked for me.
I just want to get the error response body in pojo object format rather then in string format.

Also tried in this manner, but no success.
[Tried in this manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQOmD.jpg)

Comment: can you add an example of the error message value? is it a JSON string? if so, it can be converted to a POJO using Gson or any other JSON converter package.

Comment: { "responseCode" : 400, "responseDescription": "{\"errorDetails\":[{\"errorCode\":6723808,\"description\":\"672300\",\"severityCode\":4},{\"errorCode\":57924,\"description\":"Not valid\"]}","responseTimestamp":"19-11-2022 12:27:41.309", "requestId":"dejkkjnjk"}      In this errorMessage the responseDescription feild is giving string value, which I need to convert in object pojo. That msg is coming from "msg" variable from the webclient method.

Comment: I have created the pojo class in the similar manner of the error response, but still I am getting in the string format response description feild value...can you please specify where the changes have to made in the code

Comment: In place of Mono<String> errorMsg = clientResponse.BodyToMono<String.class>, I have used Mono<SomePojoClass> errorMsg = clientResponse.BodyToMono<SomePojoClass.class>

Answer (score 0):

do you know what class the response is in case of an error? ResponseEntity perhaps?
you need to use a JSON converter package to convert it into a POJO, but you first need to make a POJO class of your own with the relevant fields (and make sure to name them in case sensitive manner).

then, inside the .flatMap(...) turn the String into the POJO using the converter.

Comment: In place of Mono<String> errorMsg = clientResponse.BodyToMono<String.class>, I have used Mono<SomePojoClass> errorMsg = clientResponse.BodyToMono<SomePojoClass.class>...Is this the correct approach